# SKSTableView Scrolling Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I am currently using this custom/ expandable tableview code called SKSTableView which can be found at [Here](https://github.com/sakkaras/SKSTableView)

Here's the issue, when I fill the table with over 10 rows, the UI Locks up and the scrolling begins to be extremely laggy. I can't seem to be able to track down the issue, but I am thinking it has something to do with reusing the cell.

Here's some code that will hopefully help.

-SKSTableView hasn't changed

-Below is the implementation in the actual file /Home Screen of app

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Bar *bar = [bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *friendsAtBar = (NSArray*)bar.friends;



    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SKSTableViewCell";
    SKSTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell){//If no cell, create a new one
        cell = [[SKSTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UIColor *cellBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:( 30/255.0) alpha:1.0];
        UIColor *cellTextColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.80 alpha:1.0];

        UIImageView *bottomLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 73, 320, 2)];
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:( 50/255.0) alpha:1.0];

        cell.nameLabel.textColor = cellTextColor;
        cell.friendsLabel.textColor = cellTextColor;
        cell.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
        cell.selectionBanner.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
        [cell addSubview:bottomLine];
        [cell.goingButton addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(goingButtonPressed:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.nameLabel.frame = nameStartFrame;


    }
    if (friendsAtBar != nil && friendsAtBar.count != 0)
        cell.isExpandable = YES;
    else
        cell.isExpandable = NO;

    cell.nameLabel.text = bar.name;
    //cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    if (friendsAtBar.count == 1) // If only 1 friend is going, say friend, if more than 1 friend is going say friends
        cell.friendsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu friend going",(unsigned long)friendsAtBar.count];
    else if (friendsAtBar.count > 1)
        cell.friendsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu friends going",(unsigned long)friendsAtBar.count];
    else {

        cell.friendsLabel.text = @"";
        //cell.nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 26, 200, 23);
    }

    //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;



    [self deselectGoingButton:cell.goingButton];
    if ([bar.objectID isEqualToString:[currentUser objectForKey:@"currentBarID"]] && [self under15Hours:[currentUser objectForKey:@"barTimeStamp"]])
    {
        goingToBarID = bar.objectID; // HERE
        //NSLog(@"goingToBarID from cell: %@",goingToBarID);
        selectedGoingToButton = cell.goingButton;
        [self selectGoingButton:cell.goingButton];
    }

    cell.goingButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.selectionBanner.tag = indexPath.row;


    return cell;
}




#pragma mark - TableView - Subrow

- (NSInteger)tableView:(SKSTableView *)tableView numberOfSubRowsAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (bars != nil && bars.count != 0) {

        Bar *bar = [bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return bar.friends.count;
    }
    else
        return 0;
} // PARSE IMPACTED
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForSubRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //NSMutableDictionary *bar = [bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Bar *bar = [bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *friendsAtBar = (NSArray*)bar.friends;

    //UIColor *cellBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:( 20/255.0) alpha:1.0];
    //UIColor *cellTextColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.85 alpha:1.0];

    UIImageView *bottomLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 73, 320, 2)];
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:( 50/255.0) alpha:1.0];

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FriendsGoingCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    UIView *cellView;
    UILabel *nameLabel;
    UILabel *usernameLabel;
    UIButton *callButton;
    UIButton *textButton;
    if (!cell){//If no cell, make a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cellView = [self createSubRowView];
        nameLabel = [cellView.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
        usernameLabel = [cellView.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
        usernameLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:1.0];
        callButton = [cellView.subviews objectAtIndex:3];
        textButton = [cellView.subviews objectAtIndex:4];
        [cell addSubview:cellView];
        [cell addSubview:bottomLine];

    }
    //cell.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
    cell.tag = 2;


    //PFUser *user = [friendsAtBar objectAtIndex:indexPath.subRow-1];
    Friend *user = [friendsAtBar objectAtIndex:indexPath.subRow-1];

    //UILabel *nameLabel = [cellView.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    //nameLabel.text = [[friendsAtBar objectAtIndex:indexPath.subRow-1] objectForKey:@"username"];
    nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.compositeName];
    //nameLabel.textColor = cellTextColor;

   // UILabel *usernameLabel = [cellView.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
    usernameLabel.text = user.userName;

    //UIButton *callButton = [cellView.subviews objectAtIndex:3];
    callButton.tag = indexPath.subRow-1;

    //UIButton *textButton = [cellView.subviews objectAtIndex:4];
    textButton.tag = indexPath.subRow-1;



    return cell;
    }
```

[self createSubView]

```
- (UIView *)createSubRowView {

    UIView *cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [rowHeight floatValue])];

    UIColor *fontColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.85 alpha:1.0];


    UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cellView.frame];
    bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15 alpha:1.0];
    [cellView addSubview:bgview];


    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 16, 180, 23)];
    nameLabel.textColor = fontColor;
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    [cellView addSubview:nameLabel];


    UILabel *goingTimeStampLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 41, 180, 16)];
    goingTimeStampLabel.textColor = fontColor;
    goingTimeStampLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [cellView addSubview:goingTimeStampLabel];


    CGFloat x = 200;
    CGFloat width = 55;
    CGFloat height = [rowHeight floatValue];
    CGFloat y = ([rowHeight floatValue] - height)/2;

    UIButton *callButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    UIImage *callIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"call.png"];
    [callButton setImage:callIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [callButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(clickedCallButton:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cellView addSubview:callButton];


    UIButton *textButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+width, y, width, height)];
    UIImage *textIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"text.png"];
    [textButton setImage:textIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [textButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(clickedTextButton:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cellView addSubview:textButton];

    return cellView;
}
```

SKSTableView.m

```
#import "SKSTableView.h"
#import "SKSTableViewCell.h"
#import "SKSTableViewCellIndicator.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

#pragma mark - NSArray (SKSTableView)

@interface NSMutableArray (SKSTableView)

- (void)initiateObjectsForCapacity:(NSInteger)numItems;

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (SKSTableView)

- (void)initiateObjectsForCapacity:(NSInteger)numItems
{
    for (NSInteger index = [self count]; index < numItems; index++) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self addObject:array];
    }
}

@end

#pragma mark - SKSTableView


@interface SKSTableView () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *expandedIndexPaths;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *expandableCells;

@end

@implementation SKSTableView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        _shouldExpandOnlyOneCell = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setSKSTableViewDelegate:(id<SKSTableViewDelegate>)SKSTableViewDelegate
{
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.delegate = self;

    [self setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255.0 green:236.0/255.0 blue:236.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    if (SKSTableViewDelegate)
        _SKSTableViewDelegate = SKSTableViewDelegate;
}

- (void)setSeparatorColor:(UIColor *)separatorColor
{
    [super setSeparatorColor:separatorColor];
    [SKSTableViewCellIndicator setIndicatorColor:separatorColor];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)expandedIndexPaths
{
    if (!_expandedIndexPaths)
        _expandedIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

    return _expandedIndexPaths;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)expandableCells
{
    if (!_expandableCells)
        _expandableCells = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    return _expandableCells;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

#pragma mark - Required

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] + [[[self expandedIndexPaths] objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (![self.expandedIndexPaths[indexPath.section] containsObject:indexPath]) {

        NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [self correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        SKSTableViewCell *cell = (SKSTableViewCell *)[_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];

        if ([[self.expandableCells allKeys] containsObject:tempIndexPath])
            [cell setIsExpanded:[[self.expandableCells objectForKey:tempIndexPath] boolValue]];

        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

        if (cell.isExpandable) {

            [self.expandableCells setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[cell isExpanded]]
                                     forKey:indexPath];

            UIButton *expandableButton = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
            [expandableButton addTarget:tableView
                                 action:@selector(expandableButtonTouched:event:)
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            if (cell.isExpanded) {

                cell.accessoryView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

            } else {

                if ([cell containsIndicatorView])
                    [cell removeIndicatorView];

            }

        } else {

            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            [cell removeIndicatorView];
            cell.accessoryView = nil;

        }

        return cell;

    } else {

        NSIndexPath *indexPathForSubrow = [self correspondingIndexPathForSubRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:(SKSTableView *)tableView cellForSubRowAtIndexPath:indexPathForSubrow];
        cell.backgroundView = nil;
        cell.backgroundColor = [self separatorColor];
        cell.indentationLevel = 2;

        return cell;

    }
}

#pragma mark - Optional

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if ([_SKSTableViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfSectionsInTableView:)]) {

        NSInteger numberOfSections = [_SKSTableViewDelegate numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];

        if ([self.expandedIndexPaths count] != numberOfSections)
            [self.expandedIndexPaths initiateObjectsForCapacity:numberOfSections];

        return numberOfSections;

    }

    return 1;
}



- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([_SKSTableViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:)])
        return [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    return nil;
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

#pragma mark - Optional

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([_SKSTableViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)])
        [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([_SKSTableViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:)])
        [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    SKSTableViewCell *cell = (SKSTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[SKSTableViewCell class]] && cell.isExpandable) {

        cell.isExpanded = !cell.isExpanded;

        NSIndexPath *_indexPath = indexPath;
        if (cell.isExpanded && self.shouldExpandOnlyOneCell) {

            _indexPath = [self correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [self collapseCurrentlyExpandedIndexPaths];
        }

        NSInteger numberOfSubRows = [self numberOfSubRowsAtIndexPath:_indexPath];

        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSInteger row = _indexPath.row;
        NSInteger section = _indexPath.section;

        for (NSInteger index = 1; index <= numberOfSubRows; index++) {

            NSIndexPath *expIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row+index inSection:section];
            [indexPaths addObject:expIndexPath];
        }

        if (cell.isExpanded) {

            [self setIsExpanded:YES forCellAtIndexPath:_indexPath];
            [self insertExpandedIndexPaths:indexPaths forSection:_indexPath.section];

        } else {

            [self setIsExpanded:NO forCellAtIndexPath:_indexPath];
            [self removeExpandedIndexPaths:indexPaths forSection:_indexPath.section];

        }

        [self accessoryViewAnimationForCell:cell];

    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([_SKSTableViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:)])
        [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self.delegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGFloat height = 0;
    if ([_SKSTableViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:)])
        height = [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];

    return height;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    if ([_SKSTableViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:)])
        view = [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:section];

    return view;
}

#pragma mark - SKSTableViewUtils

- (IBAction)expandableButtonTouched:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];

    if (indexPath)
        [self tableView:self accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSubRowsAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:self numberOfSubRowsAtIndexPath:[self correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSInteger row = 0;

    while (index < indexPath.row) {

        NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [self correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:indexPath.section]];
        BOOL isExpanded = [[self.expandableCells allKeys] containsObject:tempIndexPath] ? [[self.expandableCells objectForKey:tempIndexPath] boolValue] : NO;

        if (isExpanded) {

            NSInteger numberOfExpandedRows = [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:self numberOfSubRowsAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];

            index += (numberOfExpandedRows + 1);

        } else
            index++;

        row++;

    }

    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:indexPath.section];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)correspondingIndexPathForSubRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSInteger row = 0;
    NSInteger subrow = 0;

    while (1) {

        NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [self correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:indexPath.section]];
        BOOL isExpanded = [[self.expandableCells allKeys] containsObject:tempIndexPath] ? [[self.expandableCells objectForKey:tempIndexPath] boolValue] : NO;

        if (isExpanded) {

            NSInteger numberOfExpandedRows = [_SKSTableViewDelegate tableView:self numberOfSubRowsAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];

            if ((indexPath.row - index) <= numberOfExpandedRows) {
                subrow = indexPath.row - index;
                break;
            }

            index += (numberOfExpandedRows + 1);

        } else
            index++;

        row++;
    }

    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForSubRow:subrow inRow:row inSection:indexPath.section];
}

- (void)setIsExpanded:(BOOL)isExpanded forCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *correspondingIndexPath = [self correspondingIndexPathForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.expandableCells setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isExpanded] forKey:correspondingIndexPath];
}

- (void)insertExpandedIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSIndexPath *firstIndexPathToExpand = indexPaths[0];
    NSIndexPath *firstIndexPathExpanded = nil;

    if ([self.expandedIndexPaths[section] count] > 0) firstIndexPathExpanded = self.expandedIndexPaths[section][0];

    __block NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (firstIndexPathExpanded && firstIndexPathToExpand.section == firstIndexPathExpanded.section && firstIndexPathToExpand.row < firstIndexPathExpanded.row) {

        [self.expandedIndexPaths[section] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSIndexPath *updated = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([obj row] + [indexPaths count])
                                                      inSection:[obj section]];

            [array addObject:updated];
        }];

        [array addObjectsFromArray:indexPaths];

        self.expandedIndexPaths[section] = array;

    } else {

        [self.expandedIndexPaths[section] addObjectsFromArray:indexPaths];

    }

    [self sortExpandedIndexPathsForSection:section];

    // Reload TableView
    [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

}


- (void)removeExpandedIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSUInteger index = [self.expandedIndexPaths[section] indexOfObject:indexPaths[0]];

    [self.expandedIndexPaths[section] removeObjectsInArray:indexPaths];

    if (index == 0) {

        __block NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self.expandedIndexPaths[section] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSIndexPath *updated = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([obj row] - [indexPaths count])
                                                      inSection:[obj section]];

            [array addObject:updated];
        }];

        self.expandedIndexPaths[section] = array;

    }

    [self sortExpandedIndexPathsForSection:section];

    // Reload Tableview
    [self deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

}

- (void)collapseCurrentlyExpandedIndexPaths
{
    NSArray *expandedCells = [self.expandableCells allKeysForObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    if (expandedCells.count > 0) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [expandedCells firstObject];
        [self.expandableCells setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:indexPath];
        [self removeExpandedIndexPaths:[self.expandedIndexPaths[indexPath.section] copy] forSection:indexPath.section];

        SKSTableViewCell *cell = (SKSTableViewCell *)[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.isExpanded = NO;
        [self accessoryViewAnimationForCell:cell];
    }
}

- (void)sortExpandedIndexPathsForSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [self.expandedIndexPaths[section] sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        if ([obj1 section] < [obj2 section])
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        else if ([obj1 section] > [obj2 section])
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        else {

            if ([obj1 row] < [obj2 row])
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            else
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;

        }
    }];
}

- (void)accessoryViewAnimationForCell:(SKSTableViewCell *)cell
{
    __block SKSTableViewCell *_cell = cell;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        if (_cell.isExpanded) {

            _cell.accessoryView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

        } else {
            _cell.accessoryView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        if (!_cell.isExpanded)
            [_cell removeIndicatorView];

    }];
}

@end

#pragma mark - NSIndexPath (SKSTableView)

static void *SubRowObjectKey;

@implementation NSIndexPath (SKSTableView)

@dynamic subRow;

- (NSInteger)subRow
{
    id subRowObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, SubRowObjectKey);
    return [subRowObj integerValue];
}

- (void)setSubRow:(NSInteger)subRow
{
    id subRowObj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:subRow];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, SubRowObjectKey, subRowObj, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSubRow:(NSInteger)subrow inRow:(NSInteger)row inSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
    indexPath.subRow = subrow;

    return indexPath;
}

@end
```

Comment: What does `[self createSubRowView]` look like? In general, you have a bunch of issues here where you are re-adding identical subviews to the same cells repeatedly. (all of those `addSubview` calls should only occur in the `!cell` if statement case in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) You are doing this in both of your cell methods with in the top one `bottomLine`,  and `cellView` and `bottomLine` in the bottom one.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, i'll try that and see if it works. In the mean time I added the createSubrrowView method @Dima

Comment: So I did what you said, and any time there was drawing, I put it into the if statement that you were talking about... tableview still lagging though @Dima

Comment: Can you post your updated code for the other 2 methods?

Comment: Okay, in general this looks okay now. There are some inefficiencies but nothing that would cause that type of issue. Have you tried getting rid of the subrows and keeping just the normal cells to see if the problem persists? I suspect the issue is somewhere in `SKSTableView` which seems to have some performance issues.

Comment: @Dima The profiler shows for scrolling the tableview a very heavy stack trace for this piece of code Located in SKSTableView.m: BOOL isExpanded = [[self.expandableCells allKeys] containsObject:tempIndexPath] ? [[self.expandableCells objectForKey:tempIndexPath] boolValue] : NO; Also he shows high cpu usage for expanding a cell in the UITableView API: // Reload TableView [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

Comment: @anotherDeveloper please if you can help me; i use same code but i've big text and when the cell expand only take one line; how i can solve this to show all the text